# Erro na máscara monetária, salva com os dígitos certos mas na hora de exibir faltam 2 dígitos

Tags: java, android, edittext, mask, number-format

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Colegas! 
Quando eu salvo o produto fica com os dígitos corretos como na tela acima. 
Porém, quando eu entro na lista de produtos e clico no produto Tesoura ele abre na tela de cadastro faltando dois dígitos como na tela abaixo. Alguém tem alguma sugestão ? Peço para serem o mais específicos possíveis pois não tenho Muita experiência. Desde já agradeço a quem puder ajudar. Obrigado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Minha Classe Cadastro de produto:

```
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.app.AlertDialog;
 import android.content.DialogInterface;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.graphics.Bitmap;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.text.Editable;
 import android.text.TextWatcher;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.EditText;
 import android.widget.ImageView;
 import android.widget.Toast;
 import br.gestaoBd.BancoDeDados.ProdutoDao;
 import br.gestaoBd.Beans.Produto;
 import java.text.NumberFormat;
 import java.util.Locale;

 public class CadProdutos extends Activity {

private ImageView imgView = null;
static final int SALVAR = 0, EXCLUIR = 1, LIMPAR = 2;
EditText edId, edDescricao, edPrecoDeCusto, edPercDeLucro, edPrecoDeVenda;
ProdutoDao prodDao;
Produto produto;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.cad_produtos);
    edId = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cadEdId);
    edDescricao = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cadEdDescricao);
    edPrecoDeCusto = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cadEdPrecoDeCusto);
    edPrecoDeCusto.addTextChangedListener(new MonetaryMask(edPrecoDeCusto));
    edPercDeLucro = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cadEdPercDeLucro);
    edPrecoDeVenda = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cadEdPrecoDeVenda);
    edPrecoDeVenda.addTextChangedListener(new MonetaryMask(edPrecoDeVenda));

    imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgFoto);

    Produto produtoRecebido = (Produto) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("Produto");
    if (produtoRecebido != null) {
        montaTela(produtoRecebido);
    } else {
        montaTela(new Produto());
    }

    Button btn1Salvar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btSalvar);
    btn1Salvar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Produto pro = new Produto();
            pro.setId(Integer.valueOf(edId.getText().toString()));
            pro.setDescricao(edDescricao.getText().toString());
            pro.setPrecoDeCusto(MonetaryMask.stringMonetarioToDouble(edPrecoDeCusto.getText().toString()));
            pro.setPercDeLucro(Double.valueOf(edPercDeLucro.getText().toString()));
            pro.setPrecoDeVenda(MonetaryMask.stringMonetarioToDouble(edPrecoDeVenda.getText().toString()));

            if (pro.getId() > 0) {
                getProDao().alterar(pro);
            } else {
                getProDao().inserirProduto(pro);
            }
            ToastManager.show(getBaseContext(), "Salvo com Sucesso",
                    ToastManager.INFORMATION);

        }
    });

    Button btnLimpar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btLimpar);

    btnLimpar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            montaTela(new Produto());
        }
    });

    Button bt2Excluir = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt2Excluir);
    bt2Excluir.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            final Produto pro = new Produto();
            pro.setId(Integer.valueOf(edId.getText().toString()));
            pro.setDescricao(edDescricao.getText().toString());
            pro.setPrecoDeCusto(Double.valueOf(edPrecoDeCusto.getText().toString()));
            pro.setPercDeLucro(Double.valueOf(edPercDeLucro.getText().toString()));
            pro.setPrecoDeVenda(Double.valueOf(edPrecoDeVenda.getText().toString()));

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(CadProdutos.this);
            builder.setTitle("Deseja Excluir?");
            builder.setMessage("O produto será deletado!");

            builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    getProDao().excluir(pro);
                    montaTela(new Produto());
                    ToastManager.show(getBaseContext(), "Produto Excluído",
                            ToastManager.INFORMATION);

                }

            });

            builder.setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Toast.makeText(CadProdutos.this, "Cancelado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();

        }
    });
}

private void montaTela(Produto produto) {
    edId.setText(String.valueOf(produto.getId()));
    edDescricao.setText(produto.getDescricao());
    edPrecoDeCusto.setText(String.valueOf(produto.getPrecoDeCusto()));
    edPercDeLucro.setText(String.valueOf(produto.getPercDeLucro()));
    edPrecoDeVenda.setText(String.valueOf(produto.getPrecoDeVenda()));


}

public ProdutoDao getProDao() {
    if (prodDao == null) {
        prodDao = new ProdutoDao();
    }
    return prodDao;
}

public void tirarFoto(View view) {
    Intent i = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
    startActivityForResult(i, 0);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (data != null) {
        Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();

        if (bundle != null) {

            Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) bundle.get("data");


            imgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Minhas Classe Monetary Mask

```
 import android.text.Editable;
 import android.text.TextWatcher;
 import android.widget.EditText;
 import java.text.NumberFormat;

 public class MonetaryMask implements TextWatcher {

final EditText campo;

public static double stringMonetarioToDouble(String str) {
    double retorno = 0;
    try {
        boolean hasMask = ((str.indexOf("R$") > -1 || str.indexOf("$") > -1) && (str
                .indexOf(".") > -1 || str.indexOf(",") > -1));
        if (hasMask) {
            str = str.replaceAll("[R$]", "").replaceAll("\\,\\w+", "")
                    .replaceAll("\\.\\w+", "");
        }

        retorno = Double.parseDouble(str);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {

    }
    return retorno;
}

public MonetaryMask(EditText campo) {
    super();
    this.campo = campo;
}

private boolean isUpdating = false;

private NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
        int after) {

    if (isUpdating) {
        isUpdating = false;
        return;
    }

    isUpdating = true;
    String str = s.toString();

    boolean hasMask = ((str.indexOf("R$") > -1 || str.indexOf("$") > -1)
            && (str.indexOf(".") > -1 || str.indexOf(",") > -1));

    if (hasMask) {

        str = str.replaceAll("[R$]", "").replaceAll("[,]", "")
                .replaceAll("[.]", "");
    }

    try {

        str = nf.format(Double.parseDouble(str) / 100);
        campo.setText(str);
        campo.setSelection(campo.getText().length());
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        s = "";
    }
}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
        int after) {

}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

}

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema está no método estático `stringMonetarioToDouble(String)`: ele perde informação ao converter a String e retorna erroneamente para a camada de persistência que ao recuperar um `Produto` exibe valores incorretos. Alguns exemplos:

> "R$ 0,10" = 0.0
>
> "R$ 0,01" = 0.0
>
> "R$ 1,00" = 1.0
>
> "R$ 10,00" = 10.0
>
> "R$ 10,00" = 10.0
>
> "R$ 10,50" = 10.0

Um saída seria na classe `MonetaryMask` salvar o input original do usuário e adicionar um método que devolveria o valor **double** baseado no original e não no "mascarado". Por exemplo:

```
public class MonetaryMask implements TextWatcher {

    // ...

    private String mRawInput;
    
    // ...

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
            int after) {

        // ...
        
        mRawInput = new String(s.toString());
        
        String str = s.toString();

        // ...
    }

    public double getMonetarioAsDouble() {
        if (mRawInput == null) {
            return 0.0d;
        }
        
        return Double.parseDouble(mRawInput) / 100.0d;
    }
}
```

Dessa forma, você deve salvar as instâncias de `MonetaryMask` utilizadas. Como nesse trecho:

```
    private MonetaryMask mPrecoDeCustoMonetaryMask;
    
    // ...
    
    mPrecoDeCustoMonetaryMask = new MonetaryMask(edPrecoDeCusto);
    
    edPrecoDeCusto.addTextChangedListener(mPrecoDeCustoMonetaryMask);
    
    // ...
```

E antes de persistir, deve ser utilizado o método `getMonetarioAsDouble()` da instância para salvar os campos no `Produto`:

```
    pro.setPrecoDeCusto(mPrecoDeCustoMonetaryMask.getMonetarioAsDouble());
```

Outro ponto, é que ao recuperar o `Produto` você precisa transformar o valor **double** na entrada que o usuário insere na máscara. Por exemplo, se o usuário inseriu "100" é mascarado como "R$ 1,00", mas é persistido como 1.00 e precisa virar "100" para ser setado no `EditText`. Pode ficar algo assim:

```
    private void montaTela(Produto produto) {

        // ...

        edPrecoDeCusto.setText(String.valueOf(produto.getPrecoDeCusto() * 100.0d)));

        // ... 
    }
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Seguinte.. quando eu adiciono o valor no campo ele inclui valores mas não está removendo os zeros a esquerda. Ao longo dos dias eu fiz um método para calcular o preço de custo mais o percentual de lucro e o resultado sai na preço de venda. Está ocorrendo que, quando eu mudo o foco para o preço de venda, que deve aparecer o resultado, a aplicação trava. Olhei os logs e vi Invalid double "R$0,010".

Comment: Isso deve ser porque você está tratanto o valor mascarado como o valor final. Mas acredito que isso seja outro problema. Se você não consertar o erro do método estático `stringMonetarioToDouble(String)` de alguma forma, os problemas vão continuar.